# Selecting the kendo grid row on DetailExpand event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a Kendo grid with detail template. When I open the detail template, I want the respective row to be selected. By default, the detail expands but the row isn't selected.

```
.Events(e => e.Change("onChange").DetailExpand("jsFunction"))
```

I know there's a `DetailExpand` event that fires when the detail is expanded, I just don't know how to make it select the row to which it refers. I have tried:

```
function jsFunction() {
    this.dataItem(this.select());   <--- breaks here because there's no row selected
}
```

How can I make it select the row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is easier:

```
function jsFunction(e) {
    e.sender.select(e.masterRow);
}
```

Grettings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is simple! (Even easy, once you know it)